# SQLCE 4 - EF4.1 Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce, shared-memory

Hi im trying to run my MVC 3 application running SQLCE 4 embedded and EF4.1

i have used the data access methods as described in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

This works perfectly locally(obviously), but when running it on my hosting i get the below error message. It is a shared hosting enviroment.

Is it an open connection that is the problem? Shouldn't it be handled by the unit of work class that is returning the dbcontext as a singleton throughout the whole application as mentioned in the tutorial?

Any tips on what this might be caused by would be appreciated

Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Internal
>   error: Cannot open the shared memory region.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
   [SqlCeException (0x80004005): Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region.]
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) +40
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent) +2542
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open() +113
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +67

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +10975150
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +142
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +97
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +66
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +47
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +220
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +383
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash() +349
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +109
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +373
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +64

[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +152
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +199
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +193
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +235
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +89
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues) +37
   Web.Infrastructure.DataAccess.Repository`1.GetByID(Object id) +131
   Web.Controllers.PagesController.Home() +154
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +784922
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +784976
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that the SQL Server Compact database file is located on a shared folder, not a local drive. That will not work.

Comment: The SqlserverCE.DLL and the Sqlserverce.entity.dll are in the BIN folder. the two folders amd64 and x86 are also in the bin folder. the .sdf file is in the APP_DATA folder. I tested uploading the application to another hosting provider and the app works. So it must be a server configuration. I am no IIS expert, so what should i   ask from my host where the app works regarding rights and permissions? So i can inform the hosting provider where the app does not work of the server settings.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know pressing enter would post the comment so i accidentally posted an unfinished comment. i updated the comment above now...

Comment: As I said: This error indicates that the SQL Server Compact database file is located on a shared folder, not a local drive. Ask your hosting provider if your web site is on local drive or shared folder.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will send an email to my hosting provider and update this thread later with more info

Comment: I finally got a reply from my hosting provider and they say files are on smb share, not local. Do you know if there is any possibility solving this issue Erik?

Comment: Move to a different hoster or ask them to move the files locally (probably not going to happen), or change to SQL Server.